# html/css - Split a td in a variable number of colors

Tags: html, css, html-table

Right now I have a table where a td can have a single background color:

[image]

built with the following code:

```
<td colspan="1" style="background: cyan; position:relative;" ><span class="CellComment" class="smallCell">Version 1.0</td>
```

But on specific cases, I would "split" the td in several colors. To do that, I tried to put a number of div inside the td, each with a specific background color. (they should take all the space of the td, splitting it in equal parts)

Clearly it must be dynamic, meaning that the code that handle the one-color case and the multiple-color case must be the same. So if there is only one color, the related div must take the whole space of the td.

I used the following code:

```
<td colspan="1"><div style="background-color:cyan; position:absolute;"></div><span class="CellComment" class="smallCell">Version 1.0</td>
```

(the span is a popup that appears on mouse hover)

Nevertheless the result is disappointing:

[image]

and even when there is only one div, it takes only half of the space.

Comment: Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: is it not? the table is something big (>1000 rows and >100 columns) and so the code generating it.

Comment: Wrap those individual divs into an additional container element, and apply flexbox properties to that, that is the easiest way to divide the available width equally to all children. (You can’t apply flexbox to the `td` element itself, that would likely ruin the display of the table itself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #DF0000, #DF0000 50px, #000000 50px, #000000 100px)` to have multiple colors inside 1 div (or td) no need to make it harder

```css
#normal{
 background-color: black;
}
#split {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #DF0000, #DF0000 50px, #000000 50px, #000000 100px)
}
#split3{
background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#DF0000, #DF0000 33px,#4286f4 33px, #4286f4 66px,#000000 66px, #000000 100px)
}
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="normal">
</div>
<div id="split">
</div>
<div id="split3">
</div>
```